# How to ensure certain class members are initialized before use

Tags: c#, c++

I was thinking about language constructs and how when we talk about classes and objects in Object oriented languages we draw comparisons to real world. Like when people talk of Inheritance people would quote an example of Parent and Children. One thing that i don't find in OO languages that i know , mainly C, C++, C#, is that they don't have a mechanism to declare a property as mandatory. What i mean by that is I cannot define a class called human and say that face, hands and lets say eye are mandatory property of my class. By having that construct i can enforce that anyone who is using my class need to set those properties before using my class. If user forgets to set those properties then i should get an compile time error.

Just wanted to see community thoughts on that.

Here is reason why i had asked above question:

When i build my user controls, i want to make sure that users should set some of the properties in their code when they use my control. For example, lets say i build a customer user control that would be used by other developers in my team. Some of the properties that i have exposed are: "CustomerId", "FirstName", "LastName", "Address1", "City", "State" and ZipCode. Now i want to make sure that any consumer of my control should set "CustomerId". Using Constructor to enforce that the value is set is a way but it will throw a run time exception plus how would user call that constructor from .cs file without dynamically creating the control and adding it to control collection.

Comment: *"One thing that i don't find in OO languages that i know , mainly C"* C is not an OO language last I checked.  Aside from that, neither C nor C++ have a notion of "properties" baked into the language.

Comment: you can define multiple constructors for a class. one that takes a face, hands and an eye as an argument, one that takes a face and hands and one that only takes an eye if you wish to.

Comment: sorry about that, you are correct..C is no OO language.

Comment: Are you familiar with constructors?

Comment: Only one minor problem with that idea. How do you set all four in one go...

Comment: @Osiris: You can delete comments...

Comment: Yes, I am. Constructor is a run time enforcement mechanism and not compile time.

Comment: @CSC: that is not true at all.  Where did you get that idea?  If you only define a constructor which takes some number of arguments than failing to pass in said arguments when creating an instance of the class is a *compile time* error.  If you're talking about validation of the arguments at compile time then no, that makes absolutely no sense and is impossible in most situations.

Comment: Here is problem with using constructor. Lets say there are multiple constructors in my class. Until and unless i enforce mandatory property check in every constructor, I cannot be sure that users are settings those properties before using my class.I wan't that irrespective of whichever constructor they are using, if they haven't set the mandatory properties, compiler should be able catch that. One mechanism could be tagging a property as "Mandatory". If consumer of my class forgets to set that property then because the property was tagged as "Mandatory" compile can report that.

Comment: That's an imaginary problem.  Yes, you have to write code to do this. It's not magically done for you.  However, you should *not* be proving *any* constructors which fail to initialize required data.  Also, in C#, you can chain constructors, so there is no duplicated code.  It's really that simple. If you are doing that then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I still don't see any reason as to why it would be bad idea for language to support a construct to tag a property as mandatory. So far all i have seen is that it can be achieved by using constructors but as indicated in my "imaginary" problem, there would be cases where that construct can be really useful.

Comment: They do support just what you are asking for... via constructors... I don't understand the confusion.  Constructors with arguments tell users of the class "hey, if you want to create one of me, you'll have to supply these values".

Comment: You are right this can be done with constructor but that is run time check whereas i want the check to be enforced by compiler. Here is reason why i asked the question. I was working on ASP .Net project. We had user controls on which people had defined properties. When consumer of those controls forget to set certain properties those kinds of bugs are hard to debug and time consuming. I agree that you  create constructor and then check the values for those properties but having a construct that tells that this is mandatory property and giving compile time error would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that state needed to fulfil class invariants should be provided during object construction, so you should provide values of 'mandatory' properties as constructor parameters. Your question is based on false assumption that an object is characterized by setting state with properties. This is wrong for a handful of reasons, some of which are:

- many, if not most OO languages have no properties: Java, C++,...
- what you use is only formally an object, it is actually a plain record and it is not very object oriented, same as e.g. C++ struct without methods (see notes at the bottom about setters vs methods)

Allowing the client to create instances of the objects which are only later set up with correct values for mandatory state is sure-fire way to spend many hours in company of debugger.

Let's take some `User` with invariant that first and last name must always be set.

```
class User {
    public User(string first, string last) { ... }
    public User(string first, string last, uint age) : this(first, last) { ... }
}

// client code:
var user = new User("john", "doe");
var user2 = new User("Clint", "Eastwood", 82);
```

Compiler ensures that no one can instantiate the object without fulfilling the invariants.

Now compare it with your approach:

```
class User {
    public User(string first, string last) { ... }
    public User(uint age)  { ... }
    [Mandatory] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Mandatory] public string LastName { get; set; }
}

// client code:
var actor = new User(82); // << invalid
actor.FirstName = "Clint";
actor.LastName = "Eastwood"; // << valid
```

This approach results in more code and allows for a period of time (between `<< invalid` and `<< valid`) where your object is not in a valid state. What if some of property setters throw an exception? You are left with broken object instance floating around. Do you expect the compiler to also verify that code in the setter can not throw? Do you think it is even possible? Besides that, every client which instantiates `User` instances must check what are the mandatory properties and make sure to set all of them. This effectively breaks encapsulation.

IMO, property setters should be rare, unlike getters. I believe that in such a class you should not have setters for FirstName/LastName, only getters. Instead there should be a method `SetName(string first, string last)` if you really want to allow name changing. Here's why:

```
// lets rename actor
actor.FirstName = "John";
actor.LastName = "Wayne";
```

If the last line throws, you are left with John Eastwood, an actor I have never heard about. With `actor.SetName("John", "Wayne")` this can't happen.

Additionally, what about property which have dependency in order you specify them, e.g.

```
obj.ErrorCode = 123;  // imagine that error code must be != 0
obj.ErrorMsg = "foo"; // in order to be allowed to set error code
```

Would you also introduce attributes for that instead of having `obj.SetErrorInfo(123, "foo")`? This makes it obvious that properties break encapsulation as the order is caused by the implementation detail, unlike with method call.

Quite often, in languages like C#, required state or dependencies is provided in constructor while optional state can be set through properties. However, it is not properties or inheritance which make a language object-oriented.

Comment: Thanks Vojkovic. I agree with your comments but all i am looking for here is a compiler help to catch issues that might can be caught during compile time. Tagging a property as mandatory would be helpful in cases where class have multiple constructors.

Comment: You shouldn't allow having constructors which leave the created object  in invalid state - it is simple as that. There is no point in moving this check to properties if you already know what is required. Why would you force the user to create the object AND set properties if you can put all of that logic into a place where it belongs: the constructor.

Comment: I guess what i am not able to communicate effectively here is that i do agree that constructor is "a" mechanism to enforce mandatory properties for your classes but that mechanism is triggered at runtime. With the "contruct" i am proposing that mechanism would be enforcing the "mandatory" nature of property at compile time.

Comment: I disagree. Constructor is a mechanism which is triggered at compile time, you just need to provide appropriate constructors - compiler will force you to call them, you can not work around that. It is not harder to ensure proper ctors, then it is to add properties and mark them as mandatory. The latter only makes it possible to split construction into multiple phases and have stages when object is invalid - you want to avoid that. Besides, that would force the clients to know about your class invariants, which breaks encapsulation.

Comment: It is not uncommon for classes to have more than one constructor. If i  go via route of constructors then i have to implement logic in every constructor. Whereas having a tag to property will help. To your last point, knowing that certain property is mandatory is not different than making user pass same set of arguments in constructor . It won't break encapsulation.

Comment: no you don't have to reimplement anything. In C# you just delegate to another constructor, as shown in my example. In C++ you call a private method. It's trivial. Additionally, it is near impossible to ensure correctness of multi stage initialization - see my comments about exception. Encapsulation would be broken, as you force each client to read all the details about your properties, which should not be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vojkovic. Thats a great example and explanation. I appreciate your feedback and explanation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26106/discussion-between-csc-and-zdeslav-vojkovic)

Comment: sorry, no time for chat, and that also has no benefit for other users. feel free to extend this question or post another one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, with a DDD principle: create a class with a private default constructor, and a public constructor that accept required parameters and validate its values. If a value is invalid, throw an exception so that the object cannot be created. Properties could also have private setters instead of public setters.

You can also create a 'Mandatory' attribute and put those on top of the properties that are mandatory; and have a mechanism that checks this based on whether a property has been decorated with the attribute or not.

Example:

```
public class BlogEntry 
{
    private BlogEntry() {}
    public BlogEntry(string title, string body)
    {
        LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Title = title;
        Body = body;

        var blogEntryValidator = new BlogEntryValidator();
        blogEntryValidator.ValidateAndThrow(this);     
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? LastPublishDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; private set; }        

    public void Publish()
    {
        LastPublishDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Unpublish()
    {
        LastPublishDate = null;
    }

    public void Modify(string title, string body)
    {
        Title = title;
        Body = body;
        LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Comment AddComment(string commentText, string emailAddress, string name)
    {
        var comment = new Comment(this, commentText, emailAddress, name);
        if (Comments == null) Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Comments.Add(comment);
        return comment;
    }

    public void RemoveComment(Comment comment)
    {
        Comments.Remove(comment);
    }
}

public class Comment 
{
    private Comment() {}
    public Comment(BlogEntry blogEntry, string name, string emailAddress, string commentText)
    {            
        BlogEntry = blogEntry;
        Name = name;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        CommentText = commentText;
        DateWritten = DateTime.Now;

        var commentValidator = new CommentValidator();
        commentValidator.ValidateAndThrow(this);    
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }        
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; private set; }
    public string CommentText { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateWritten { get; private set; }
    public BlogEntry BlogEntry { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: In the context of the two languages in question, you don't need to define a private default constructor.  If you define a constructor which requires parameters the default constructor will not be created by the compiler.

Comment: @Ed S. Actually I want a private default constructor because I want to be explicit; and maybe to provide initialization logic. Also, entity framework code first needs a default constructor to materialize the object (but it can be private). So you need this private default constructor in these cases.

Comment: I can't say I agree with the "being explicit" as the behavior of compiler generated default constructors are known to anyone beyond the "absolute beginner" level.  It's defined by the standard.  As far as initialization is concerned, it's not being called, so it's just dead code.  The EF thing, sure, but who here is talking about EF?

Comment: The example I gave was a copy paste of some of my code, so it was there because I used it in an EF context. My sincere apologies for not removing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C++ and C# allow for this via constructors.

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(int x, int y, int z)
      : _x(x_, _y(y), _z(z) {}
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _z;
};
```

You cannot create an instance of `A` without providing values for `_x`, `_y`, and `_z`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!  Just use parameters in constructor to denote which are mandatory.

```
public class Human
{
    public Face Face { get; set; }
    public Hand Hand { get; set; }

    public Human(Face face, Hand hand) {} etc...
}
```

In this instance, you cannot use the private constructor, so these properties are essentially "mandatory" in order to use the Human class.